# Loading a typical image to Django 1.3

Tags: python, django, static-libraries, django-models

I have a very basic question about adding images to Django 1.3.

I've almost read the whole documents on adding Static files, searched for relevant results and still have a problem with my case.

Please take a look at my settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/vahid/Aptana3Workspace/djangoshop/djangoShop/static'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (STATIC_ROOT ,  )
```

I did the last one to avoid collision between ROOT and DIRS and make it more simple to implement the idea.

I have also added some stuff to settings.py as:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (.....
                               'django.contrib.staticfiles',
                               .........
                               )
```

But I still have a problem with loading the images (for example: logo.jpg)

What is a simple way to load images in the developing environment?

One extra point is that I'm developing an e-commerce project with Django 1.3, And would like to present each image besides to products' info, which is saved by "models.ImageField". As you see, this is also a problem with static files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will answer your question, but for a similar purposes I either run Apache locally to serve my media, or even point Django to the live site for the media files if the live version of my site is already up and running.

I have found [photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/) suitable for all my image handling needs.

Comment: Sorry for a very late reply..
Thanks for your response. It worked perfect :)